# Command substitution not working inside for loop condition

Tags: bash, for

`for (( a=1;a<=$(wc -l sedtest1);a++ ));do echo $a; done`

Gives me an error:

`-bash: ((: a<=21 sedtest1: syntax error in expression (error token is "sedtest1")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `wc -l sedtest1` will be something like:

```
21 sedtest1
```

So the test will become something like `a <= 21 sedtest1` which is invalid.

Also, that does mean that the `wc` command will be run for each iteration of the loop. If the content of the `sedtest1` file doesn't change between each iteration, it would be better to save that number of line first in a variable outside the loop:

```
n=$(wc -l < sedtest1) # using redirection avoids the output containing the filename
for ((a = 0; a < n; a++)); do echo "$a"; done
```

I also suspect that you're trying to use a loop to process text in an inefficient and non-shell way. You may want to read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). Looping over each line of a file in that way is not the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the sources, I'll look into them!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I was just being incredibly stupid...
`wc -l file` outputs as "x file".

All I had to do was this:
`for (( a=1;a<=$(wc -l sedtest1|awk '{print $1}');a++ ));do echo $a; done`

Comment: Umm... Now you've made the code worse.  The `wc` and `awk` will be invoked in each iteration of the loop.  If the file is large, this would run very slowly.  See [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496017/116858).

Comment: Oh I didn't say my answer was better, I just figured out the problem :D